# How to populate sitemap file automatically

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

suppose my site has thousand of files. when i add sitemap file in my project then i had to add all the urls manually. it is very tiresome job. day-by-day more pages may be added in my site then again i had to put those url again in sitemap file.

so please tell me how could i populate my sitemap file automatically from VS2010 IDE. is there any way. again when any new page will be added then that entry for that page will be added in my sitemap. how to achieve this kind of automation. is there any utility available for VS2010? plzz discuss...thanks

below sitemap file is sample

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >

  <siteMapNode url="~/default.aspx" title="Home"  description="The WebSite's Home Page">

    <siteMapNode url="~/DE/index.aspx" title="DE Home"  description="DE Home">
      <siteMapNode url="~/DE/Parts.aspx" title="Part"  description="DE Part" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/DE/SubParts.aspx" title="Subpart"  description="DE Subpart" />
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="~/US/index.aspx" title="US Home"  description="US Home">
      <siteMapNode url="~/US/Parts.aspx" title="Part"  description="US Part" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/US/SubParts.aspx" title="Subpart"  description="US Subpart" />
    </siteMapNode>

    <siteMapNode url="~/UK/index.aspx" title="UK Home"  description="UK Home">
      <siteMapNode url="~/UK/Parts.aspx" title="Part"  description="UK Part" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/UK/SubParts.aspx" title="Subpart"  description="UK Subpart" />
    </siteMapNode>

     </siteMapNode>
     </siteMap>
```

if my site map file name is different then what i need to do....plzz advise. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options to consider:

http://sitemapgenerator.codeplex.com/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GoogleSiteMapProvider.aspx

http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators

Answer (score 2):

[Sitemap Generator](http://sitemapgenerator.codeplex.com/) is something that might help, but it hasn't been updated in some time. I have no experience with it myself though.

Answer (score 1):

These links might help

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/dynamicsitemap.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DynamicSitemapASPNET2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

U can use [EasySiteMap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EasySiteMap/).

It generates all necessary sitemaps with the format indicated. Also generates the sitemap_index.xml if more than one sitemap.xml has been created.